# Complex SQL Query - i found no answer :(

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

i've have a MS-SQL table which contains the following columns:

```
ID, SKU, StockID, StockQTY
```

The columns/rows are filled like:

| ID | SKU | StockID | StockQTY |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1111 | 1 | 12 |
| 2 | 1111 | 13 | 20 |
| 3 | 2222 | 1 | 0 |
| 4 | 2222 | 13 | 5 |
| 5 | 3333 | 1 | 0 |
| 6 | 3333 | 13 | 4 |

Now i need a SQL query which show all SKU (second column) which have a `StockQTY = 0 in StockID = 1 AND a StockQTY > 1 in StockID 13`. All other rows should not be shown (in this example row 1 and 2 should not be shown in the result).

Have anyone an idea how to realize this?

Comment: Why should row 2 not be shown?

Comment: MySQL (in tags) <> MS SQL (in the text)

Comment: Please share your attempts to resolve the problem

Comment: You need to correlate the SKUs with a self join using *exists*. Unfortunately the question is now closed - suggest you edit it and clearly define your expected results, it may then get re-opened.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a correlated subquery to test for skus that have 0 qty in StockID `1` and then just keep anything that has a qty greater than 1 in your StockID `13`.

```
SELECT SKU
FROM yourtable yt
WHERE Stockid = 13
   AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM yourtable WHERE StockID = 1 AND yt.SKU = SKU)
HAVING Sum(StockQty) > 1
```

Comment: I think it's just two `EXISTS` and not `SUM`.

Comment: You may right. I was really going off of "now i need a SQL query which show all SKU (second column) which have a StockQTY = 0 in StockID = 1 AND a StockQTY > 1 in StockID 13" which suggested that just the sku was needed.

Comment: I also made the assumption that there may be more than one record for each sku/stockid combination.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like:

```
SELECT SKU FROM yourTableName WHERE
(StockQTY = 0 AND StockID = 1) OR (StockQTY > 1 AND StockID = 13);
```

To pull data obviously it is a SELECT statement, you could use * instead of SKU if you want ALL the data instead of just the SKU number.  Exchange yourTableName with the actual table name.  The WHERE clause is the meat of your question.  This use of OR and AND can be confusing.  We have 2 cases we are testing.  One where the stock is 0 but the ID is 1, but we use the OR so that regardless if that is found or not, we can then do the next part where the StockQTY is 1 and the StockID is 13.  You need the and for both conditions in the own case, and you want OR so that either of these two cases will pull up.

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it

Comment: Your query will not skip ID=1 as OP seemingly requires

Comment: @PM77-1 Why not? if stockqty > 0 and stockid = 1 it wont be in result set.

Comment: ahh I started this before his edits, he corrected what he was asking it seems.  But I'm already getting hate votes for helping so , I will let others finish up.